# Thresholding a range of colors from an image

Tags: c++, c, opencv, colors, pixel

### The plan

My project is able to capture the bitmap of a target window and convert it into an `IplImage`, and then display that image in a `cvNamedWindow`, where further processing can take place.
For the sake of testing, I've loaded an image into MSPaint like so:

[image: MSPaint Test Window]

The user is then allowed to click and drag the mouse over any number of pixels within the image to create a `vector<cv::Scalar_<BYTE>>` containing these RGB color values.
Then, with the help of `ColorRGBToHLS()`, this array is then sorted from left to right by hue, like so:

```
// PixelColor is just a cv::Scalar_<BYTE>
bool comparePixelColors( PixelColor& pc1, PixelColor& pc2 ) {
    WORD h1 = 0, h2 = 0;
    WORD s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
    WORD l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
    ColorRGBToHLS(RGB(pc1.val[2], pc1.val[1], pc1.val[0]), &h1, &l1, &s1);
    ColorRGBToHLS(RGB(pc2.val[2], pc2.val[1], pc2.val[0]), &h2, &l2, &s2);
    return ( h1 < h2 );
}

//..(elsewhere in code)
std::sort(m_colorRange.begin(), m_colorRange.end(), comparePixelColors);
```

...and then shown in a new `cvNamedWindow`, which looks something like:

[image: ColorRange Window]

### The problem

Now, the idea here is to create a binary threshold image *(or "mask")* where this selected range of colors become white, and the rest of the source image becomes black... similar to the way the *"Select By Color"* tool operates in GIMP, or the *"magic wand"* tool works in Photoshop... except instead of limiting ourselves to a specific contoured selection, we are literally operating on the image as a whole.

I've read into `cvInRangeS`, and it sounds like it's precisely what I need.
However, and for whatever reason, ***the thresholded image always ends up being totally black***...

```
VOID ShowThreshedImage(const IplImage* src, const PixelColor& min, const PixelColor& max)
{
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(src, imgHSV, CV_RGB2HLS);
    cvNamedWindow("T1");
    cvShowImage("T1", imgHSV); // <-- Shows up like the image below

    IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, min, max, imgThreshed);
    cvNamedWindow("T2");
    cvShowImage("T2", imgThreshed); // <-- SHOWS UP PITCH BLACK!
}
```

This is what the `"T1"` window ends up looking like *(which I suppose is correct?)*:

[image: HSV Result Window]

**Bearing in mind** that because the color range vector is stored as RGB *(and that OpenCV internally reverses this order into BGR)*, I have converted the min/max values into HLS before passing them into `ShowThreshedImage()` like so:

```
CvScalar rgbPixelToHSV(const PixelColor& pixelColor)
{
    WORD h = 0, s = 0, l = 0;
    ColorRGBToHLS(RGB(pixelColor.val[2], pixelColor.val[1], pixelColor.val[0]), &h, &l, &s);
    return PixelColor(h, s, l);
}

//...(elsewhere in code)
if(m_colorRange.size() > 0)
    m_minHSV = rgbPixelToHSV(m_colorRange[0]);
if(m_colorRange.size() > 1)
    m_maxHSV = rgbPixelToHSV(m_colorRange[m_colorRange.size() - 1]);

ShowThreshedImage(m_imgSrc,  m_minHSV, m_maxHSV);
```

...But even without this conversion and simply passing RGB values instead, the result is still an entirely black image. I've even tried manually plugging in certain min/max values, and the best result I got was a few lit pixels (albeit, the *incorrect* ones).

### The question:

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there something that I don't understand about the `cvInRangeS` method?
Do I need to step through each and every single color in order to properly threshold the selected range out of the source image?
Are there any other ways of accomplishing this?

Thank you for your time.

### Update:

I have discovered that `cvInRangeS` expects *all values* for `min` to be lower than that of `max`. But when a range of colors are selected, there doesn't appear to be any guarantee that this will be the case, often resulting in a black thresholded image.
And swapping values to enforce this rule may result in unwanted colors within the new range (in some cases, this could include ***all*** colors instead of just the desired ones).

So I suppose the real question here would be:
***"How do you segment an array of RGB colors, and use them to threshold an image?"***

Comment: Have you mixed up min and max? Just a guess - try swapping them.

Comment: No... and as stated in the _Update_ section, you would need to swap each element of min and max where `min.val > max.val`, often resulting in a different or undesired range of colors.

Comment: Yeah soory, you updated your post while I was thinking about it. Given that cvInRangeS doesn't seem to do what you want I would scan the image.

Comment: If by 'scan' you mean iterating through every pixel in the image to check for a specific color, it would become far too inefficient (at the same time, you would need to loop through every color in the array to check for a match, resulting in exponential time increases). It could work if only a few colors were used, but my project uses live updates where it needs to show the updated window image at least once per second, so that object tracking and prediction can take place. This is the reason I need to threshold the image in the first place. But I do appreciate your suggestion, so thank you.

Comment: Your output HLS image is at least correct. OpenCV is unable to display HLS so turns it into RGB which looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by the simple fact that OpenCV maintains a different range for values than for instanc MSpaint. For instance the HSV color space in paint is 360,100,100 while in OpenCV it is 180,255,255. Check your input values in openCV bu outputting the pixel value when clicking on a certain pixel. inRangeS should be the correct tool for the job. That said, in RGB it should work just as well because the range is the same as in paint.

```
cvSetMouseCallback("MyWindow", mouseEvent, (void*) &myImage);

void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void *param) {
    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
        IplImage* imageSource = (IplImage*) param;
        Mat image(imageSource);
        cout << "Image cols " << image.cols << " rows " << image.rows << endl;
        Mat imageHSV;
        cvtColor(image, imageHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
        Vec3b p = imageHSV.at<Vec3b > (y, x);
        char text[20];
        sprintf(text, "H=%d, S=%d, V=%d", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
        cout << text << endl;
    }
}
```

When you have an idea about the HSV values by using this values, use these as lower and upper bounds for the in range method after converting the image to HSV by using `cvtColor(image, imageHSV, CV_BGR2HSV)`. That should make you able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to be too inefficient to iterate through every pixel. That is exactly what `cvInRangeS` would do - see this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way (I do this all the time and it is instantaneous for reasonable size images).

I would treat the color in the array as points in 3D RGB space. Find two color points that specify a prism that includes all other color points.  That is just finding the min and max of all r,g, and b values.  If this idea is not ok then you might have to check every image pixel against every pixel in the vector.

Then for each pixel in the image: result is black if (pixel.r < min.r) || (pixel.r > max.r) || (pixel.g < min.g) || (pixel.g > max.g) || (pixel.b < min.b) || (pixel.b > max.b), result is the pixel value otherwise.

This all should be very easy, so long as it is actually what you want.